# Value type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

Not sure where I make a mistake.

Code:

```
public class VaccinationTotalUSA extends Fragment {

RecyclerView rvRecentRecord;
ProgressBar progressBar;

private static final String TAG = VaccinationTotalUSA.class.getSimpleName();

ArrayList<VaccinationTimeline> recentRecords;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vaccination, container, false);


    // call view
    rvRecentRecord = view.findViewById(R.id.vaccinationRecord);
    progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_circular_vaccination);
    rvRecentRecord.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    // Volley Fetch
    getDataFromServer();

    return view;
}

private void showRecyclerView() {
    VaccinationAdapter vaccinationAdapter = new VaccinationAdapter(recentRecords);
    rvRecentRecord.setAdapter(vaccinationAdapter);
}

private void getDataFromServer() {
    String url = "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/vaccine/coverage/countries/USA";

    recentRecords = new ArrayList<>();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (response != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse:" + response);
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("timeline");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Iterator key = data.keys();
                        while (key.hasNext()) {
                            String timedata = key.next().toString();
                            recentRecords.add(new VaccinationTimeline(key, timedata));
                        }

                    }

                    showRecyclerView();
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse" + error);
                }
            });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(stringRequest);
}
```

}

JSON: **Note:** *Can't really use jsonObject.getString() on timeline nested list since everything gets updated each day, i.e, 4/18/2021 data comes in, 3/19/2021 will be removed*

```
{
"country": "USA",
"timeline": {
    "3/19/21": 118313818,
    "3/20/21": 121441497,
    "3/21/21": 124481412,
    "3/22/21": 126509736,
    "3/23/21": 128217029,
    "3/24/21": 130473853,
    "3/25/21": 133305295,
    "3/26/21": 136684688,
    "3/27/21": 140180735,
    "3/28/21": 143462691,
    "3/29/21": 145812835,
    "3/30/21": 147602345,
    "3/31/21": 150273292,
    "4/1/21": 153631404,
    "4/2/21": 157606463,
    "4/3/21": 161688422,
    "4/4/21": 165053746,
    "4/5/21": 167187795,
    "4/6/21": 168592075,
    "4/7/21": 171476655,
    "4/8/21": 174879716,
    "4/9/21": 178837781,
    "4/10/21": 183467709,
    "4/11/21": 187047131,
    "4/12/21": 189692045,
    "4/13/21": 192282781,
    "4/14/21": 194791836,
    "4/15/21": 198317040,
    "4/16/21": 202282923,
    "4/17/21": 202282923
}
```

}

I have tried many ways to display this json data, with and without iterator. I want to use iterator because I want to be able to retrieve both list name and data inside of list, i.e, 4/17/2021:1111111
Error Output:

```
E/VaccinationTotalUSA: onResponse:{"country":"USA","timeline":{"3/19/21":118313818,"3/20/21":121441497,"3/21/21":124481412,"3/22/21":126509736,"3/23/21":128217029,"3/24/21":130473853,"3/25/21":133305295,"3/26/21":136684688,"3/27/21":140180735,"3/28/21":143462691,"3/29/21":145812835,"3/30/21":147602345,"3/31/21":150273292,"4/1/21":153631404,"4/2/21":157606463,"4/3/21":161688422,"4/4/21":165053746,"4/5/21":167187795,"4/6/21":168592075,"4/7/21":171476655,"4/8/21":174879716,"4/9/21":178837781,"4/10/21":183467709,"4/11/21":187047131,"4/12/21":189692045,"4/13/21":192282781,"4/14/21":194791836,"4/15/21":198317040,"4/16/21":202282923,"4/17/21":202282923}}
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"country":"USA","timeline":{"3\/19\/21":118313818,"3\/20\/21":121441497,"3\/21\/21":124481412,"3\/22\/21":126509736,"3\/23\/21":128217029,"3\/24\/21":130473853,"3\/25\/21":133305295,"3\/26\/21":136684688,"3\/27\/21":140180735,"3\/28\/21":143462691,"3\/29\/21":145812835,"3\/30\/21":147602345,"3\/31\/21":150273292,"4\/1\/21":153631404,"4\/2\/21":157606463,"4\/3\/21":161688422,"4\/4\/21":165053746,"4\/5\/21":167187795,"4\/6\/21":168592075,"4\/7\/21":171476655,"4\/8\/21":174879716,"4\/9\/21":178837781,"4\/10\/21":183467709,"4\/11\/21":187047131,"4\/12\/21":189692045,"4\/13\/21":192282781,"4\/14\/21":194791836,"4\/15\/21":198317040,"4\/16\/21":202282923,"4\/17\/21":202282923}} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
        at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
        at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
        at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
        at com.programming_concept.senior_project.VaccinationTotalUSA$1.onResponse(VaccinationTotalUSA.java:83)
W/System.err:     at com.programming_concept.senior_project.VaccinationTotalUSA$1.onResponse(VaccinationTotalUSA.java:69)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: You might consider using Retrofit2, i used in in an app that loads vaccine data aswell. You can privide it with a GSONConverter factory to parse your data into java objects.  Works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set the "timeline" value to a `JSONArray` variable while that value would actually be a `JSONObject`. Here's a way you can retrieve both the key and value:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject subObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("timeline");

// Separate the keys into a JSONArray
JSONArray keys = subObject.names();

// Retrieve the keys and values
for(int i=0; i < keys.length(); i++) {
    String key = keys.getString(i);
    int value = subObject.getInt(key);
            
    Log.d("LOG_TAG", key + " : " + value);
}
```

Comment: org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray problem solved. But still getting error message(E/VaccinationTotalUSA: onResponse:{"country":"USA","timeline":{"3/19/21":118313818,"3/20/21":121441497,"3/21/21":124481412, ... 4/14/21":194791836,"4/15/21":198317040,"4/16/21":202282923,"4/17/21":202282923}}). Any idea what might cause this problem? Do I need to change array into Map since there are key and value?

Comment: It's appearing as an error because you used `Log.e()` to print that message in your `onResponse()`. You have `Log.e(TAG, "onResponse:" + response);` when I think you meant to put `Log.d(TAG, "onResponse:" + response);`

Comment: I noticed that, forgot to delete my previous comments. Thank you for the reply. Right now, I run into "No adapter attached, skipped layout" problem. If you are familiar with that, can you take look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67149764/no-adapter-attached-not-sure-where-this-problem-occurs?noredirect=1#comment118735512_67149764.

Answer (score 1):

There is no array in that JSON. In JSON, an array is denoted by square brackets (`[` and `]`). There are no square brackets in that JSON.

You have an outer JSON object, with two properties: `country` and `timeline`. `timeline` is another JSON object, with keys based on dates and values that are integers.

So, you need to revise your plans to work with the JSON as it is, which means `JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("timeline");` needs to turn into `JSONObject timelineJson = jsonObject.getJSONObject("timeline");`.

And note that there are many better JSON parsers available for Android, such as [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the follwing code. I have hardcoded the json response in the Main class itself. Also I have used ObjectMapper which is much better than using JsonObject class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


public class AssessmentBridgeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        String json = "{\"country\":\"USA\",\"timeline\":{\"3/19/21\":118313818,\"3/20/21\":121441497,\"3/21/21\":124481412,\"3/22/21\":126509736,\"3/23/21\":128217029,\"3/24/21\":130473853,\"3/25/21\":133305295,\"3/26/21\":136684688,\"3/27/21\":140180735,\"3/28/21\":143462691,\"3/29/21\":145812835,\"3/30/21\":147602345,\"3/31/21\":150273292,\"4/1/21\":153631404,\"4/2/21\":157606463,\"4/3/21\":161688422,\"4/4/21\":165053746,\"4/5/21\":167187795,\"4/6/21\":168592075,\"4/7/21\":171476655,\"4/8/21\":174879716,\"4/9/21\":178837781,\"4/10/21\":183467709,\"4/11/21\":187047131,\"4/12/21\":189692045,\"4/13/21\":192282781,\"4/14/21\":194791836,\"4/15/21\":198317040,\"4/16/21\":202282923,\"4/17/21\":202282923}}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        VaccinationRecords vaccinationRecords  = new VaccinationRecords();
        vaccinationRecords = mapper.readValue(json, VaccinationRecords.class);
        System.out.println(vaccinationRecords.getTimeline());
    }
}
```

=========================

```
import java.util.Map;

public class VaccinationRecords {

private String country;

Map<String, Object> timeline;

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public Map<String, Object> getTimeline() {
    return timeline;
}

public void setTimeline(Map<String, Object> timeline) {
    this.timeline = timeline;
}
```

}