# No adapter attached, not sure where this problem occurs

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get JSONObject data into the RecyclerView adapter, but giving me an error output in the adapter class, and shows me no adapter attached.
Two Errors:
**No adapter attached
**No package ID 07 found for ID 0x073d0cd9

JSONObject

```
onResponse:{"country":"USA","timeline":{"3/19/21":118313818,"3/20/21":121441497,"3/21/21":124481412,"3/22/21":126509736,"3/23/21":128217029,"3/24/21":130473853,"3/25/21":133305295,"3/26/21":136684688,"3/27/21":140180735,"3/28/21":143462691,"3/29/21":145812835,"3/30/21":147602345,"3/31/21":150273292,"4/1/21":153631404,"4/2/21":157606463,"4/3/21":161688422,"4/4/21":165053746,"4/5/21":167187795,"4/6/21":168592075,"4/7/21":171476655,"4/8/21":174879716,"4/9/21":178837781,"4/10/21":183467709,"4/11/21":187047131,"4/12/21":189692045,"4/13/21":192282781,"4/14/21":194791836,"4/15/21":198317040,"4/16/21":202282923,"4/17/21":202282923}}
```

Error: **Not sure where I made a mistake, I double-check the layout I attached.

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
    Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@73265c8
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe5c528c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe663e800)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe5c528c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe663e800)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe5c528c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe663e800)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe5c528c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe663e800)
E/VaccinationTotalUSA: onResponse:{"country":"USA","timeline":{"3/20/21":121441497,"3/21/21":124481412,"3/22/21":126509736,"3/23/21":128217029,"3/24/21":130473853,"3/25/21":133305295,"3/26/21":136684688,"3/27/21":140180735,"3/28/21":143462691,"3/29/21":145812835,"3/30/21":147602345,"3/31/21":150273292,"4/1/21":153631404,"4/2/21":157606463,"4/3/21":161688422,"4/4/21":165053746,"4/5/21":167187795,"4/6/21":168592075,"4/7/21":171476655,"4/8/21":174879716,"4/9/21":178837781,"4/10/21":183467709,"4/11/21":187047131,"4/12/21":189692045,"4/13/21":192282781,"4/14/21":194791836,"4/15/21":198317040,"4/16/21":202282923,"4/17/21":205871913,"4/18/21":205871913}}
E/.senior_projec: No package ID 07 found for ID 0x073d0cd9.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.programming_concept.senior_project, PID: 7781
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x73d0cd9
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5831)
        at com.programming_concept.senior_project.VaccinationAdapter.onBindViewHolder(VaccinationAdapter.java:37)
        at com.programming_concept.senior_project.VaccinationAdapter.onBindViewHolder(VaccinationAdapter.java:14)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1156)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2718)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1572)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1855)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Java class gives me this error:

```
public class VaccinationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VaccinationAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<VaccinationTimeline> recentRecords;

    public VaccinationAdapter(ArrayList<VaccinationTimeline> recentRecords) {
        this.recentRecords = recentRecords;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VaccinationAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_vaccination_record,
                parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VaccinationAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        VaccinationTimeline recentRecord = recentRecords.get(position);
        holder.tvTimeline.setText(recentRecord.getmDate());
        holder.tvCount.setText(recentRecord.getmCount());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return recentRecords.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvTimeline;
        TextView tvCount;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvTimeline = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimeline);
            tvCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCount);
        }
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">



    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vaccinationRecord"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_list_vaccination_record"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progress_circular_vaccination"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />


</RelativeLayout>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvTimeline"
            android:text="mm/dd/yyyy:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTotalConfirmed"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvCount"
            android:text="100000"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTotalConfirmed"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />



    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

More Detail(Fragment class):
Not sure if is error in this class or adapter class.

```
public class VaccinationTotalUSA extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView rvRecentRecord;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    private static final String TAG = VaccinationTotalUSA.class.getSimpleName();

    ArrayList<VaccinationTimeline> recentRecords;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vaccination, container, false);


        // call view
        rvRecentRecord = view.findViewById(R.id.vaccinationRecord);
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_circular_vaccination);
        rvRecentRecord.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        // Volley Fetch
        getDataFromServer();

        return view;
    }

    private void showRecyclerView() {
        VaccinationAdapter vaccinationAdapter = new VaccinationAdapter(recentRecords);
        rvRecentRecord.setAdapter(vaccinationAdapter);
    }

    private void getDataFromServer() {
        String url = "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/vaccine/coverage/countries/USA";

        recentRecords = new ArrayList<>();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (response != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse:" + response);
                    try {
                        
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONObject subObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("timeline");

                        JSONArray keys = subObject.names();



                        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length(); i++) {

                            String key = keys.getString(i);
                            int value = subObject.getInt(key);

                            recentRecords.add(new VaccinationTimeline(key, value));

                        }

                        showRecyclerView();
                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse" + error);
                    }
                });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're receiving the 'No adapter attached' message because you're setting the adapter from an asynchronous callback. By the time the callback returns, Android has already completed its layout pass, seen that the RecyclerView hasn't been set up yet, and has already decided to skip it.

Instead, you should set your adapter directly within `onCreateView` and update it from your callback.

Add an update method to your Adapter:

```
// Update your Adapter's member variable to instantiate a new ArrayList.
// (This will let the Layout Manager know that there are 0 items in the adapter
// initially. This way the layout can still be drawn without error before we add the
// items from our response callback.)
ArrayList<VaccinationTimeline> recentRecords = new ArrayList<>();

// Update your constructor to receive no parameters
// since the items will be updated later.
public VaccinationAdapter() {}

// ...

// Create a method to update your Adapter's items
public void updateRecords(ArrayList<VaccinationTimeline> recentRecords) {
    this.recentRecords = recentRecords;
    notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify the Adapter that the item data has changed
}
```

Set the Adapter in your `onCreateView`:

```
// Create a member variable for your Adapter
VaccinationAdapter vaccinationAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vaccination, container, false);


    // call view
    rvRecentRecord = view.findViewById(R.id.vaccinationRecord);
    progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_circular_vaccination);
    rvRecentRecord.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    
    // Set your Adapter
    vaccinationAdapter = new VaccinationAdapter();
    rvRecentRecord.setAdapter(vaccinationAdapter);

    // Volley Fetch
    getDataFromServer();

    return view;
}
```

Update the Adapter from your callback:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    
    if (response != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse:" + response);
        
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONObject subObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("timeline");
            
            JSONArray keys = subObject.names();
            
            // Collect the new values from the callback
            ArrayList<VaccinationTimeline> newRecords = new ArrayList<>():
            
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.length(); i++) {
                String key = keys.getString(i);
                int value = subObject.getInt(key);
                
                newRecords.add(new VaccinationTimeline(key, value));
            }
            
            // Update the adapter with the new values
            vaccinationAdapter.updateRecords(newRecords);
            
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will make a note of this, really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**No package ID 07 found for ID 0x073d0cd9
This problem is fixed.

I try set integer using setText(),

Original:

```
holder.tvCount.setText(recentRecord.getmCount());
```

Fixed:

```
holder.tvCount.setText(String.valueof(recentRecord.getmCount());
```

Still having no adapter attached problem. Anyone familiar with this?
I double check my layout file, and make sure I attached the right xml. Maybe I am missing something?